# Language set up with out loading whole page

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

Are there any alternate way of below code to set app language? Below code refresh the whole page always that gives bad experience to users.

```
window.location.search = "sap-language=EN";
```

This is also one way to achieve.

```
sap.ui.getCore().getConfiguration().setLanguage("EN");
```

However, some standard controls after rendered don't change the labels. Let me know if there are any other way that help here because loading whole page doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Related enhancement request: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1258#issuecomment-285421612

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax by getting all the new markup and replacing the existing content by the reloaded content.

It might create some issues with other running scripts like loading images and sliders etc that holds a reference to an element so you have to reinitialize every single script that is running on `settimeout()` on your page.

Moreover you can use [jQuery Localisation](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html) plugin

Comment: Thanks Arsal for your kind reply. Let me elaborate my requirement. User can go and select required language from the plugin but once it has chosen then he should not go and change every time for the I have back end service to pick the last selected language and condition to load that language. I need this for such case in latest sap ui5 1.52.33 version?

Comment: Yeah sure you can use a ifSelected variable to check if the language has already been selected before or not. Hope it helps.